Merging tables using python
I want to merge some 'n' tables in python. Each table has 2 columns in it. Currently, I'm trying with these 3 tables (table12, table13, table23).

Context: I have certain image files, each image has some objects inside it which are labelled as 'A', 'B', 'C', etc.
If I'm comparing 2 images, I get an equivalence table which tells which object in image1 is similar to which object of image2. (for example. first row of table12 tells that object 'A' of image1 and object 'P' of image2 are same)
There are chances that an object in one image doesn't have an equivalent object in the other image.
I want to create a single table, making use of all these tables. Number of columns in the final merged table = number of images. Means, under each column, its objects will be mentioned and in the same row, we can find which objects are similar.
I tried pandas merge (merging 2 tables, then merging third one on the merged of first and second) but it's giving result like:
.
If you want to test, here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table12 = pd.DataFrame({
    'img1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', np.NaN, np.NaN], 
    'img2': ['P', np.NaN, 'Q', np.NaN, 'R', 'S']
})

table13 = pd.DataFrame({
    'img1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', np.NaN, np.NaN], 
    'img3': [np.NaN, 'X', np.NaN, 'Y', 'Z', 'W']
})

table23 = pd.DataFrame({
    'img2': ['P', np.NaN, 'Q', np.NaN, 'R', np.NaN, 'S'],
    'img3': [np.NaN, 'X', np.NaN, 'Y', 'Z', 'W', np.NaN]
})

merged_12_13 = pd.merge(table12, table13, on='img1', how='outer')

final_output = pd.merge(merged_12_13, table23, on=['img2', 'img3'], how='outer')


Please provide a [mre] (images of data are not acceptable).

Hi @mozway, I've added the code snippet

So you want the order of the rows to remain unchanged? Are you sure there is always a match? What if you have extra rows in one of the tables?

Are the tables always correctly aligned on the top?

Your logic in unclear, but assuming that the tables are to be kept in their original order and are top aligned, you should probably concat the individual columns:
pd.concat([table12[['img1']], table23[['img2']], table13[['img3']]], axis=1)

Or, taking all columns as input and removing the duplicates:
pd.concat([table12, table13, table23], axis=1).T.groupby(level=0).first().T

Output:
  img1 img2 img3
0    A    P  NaN
1    B  NaN    X
2    C    Q  NaN
3    D  NaN    Y
4  NaN    R    Z
5  NaN    S    W
6  NaN  NaN  NaN


Does it work in Numpy 2.0? Because I got None instead of Nan.

@toyotaSupra I tested with 1.26.4. That said you can replace the None with nan after the concatenation if this is an issue
